# XSL template to excelsheet, changes not reflecting

Tags: php, xml, xslt, export-to-excel

I am trying to generate a .xls file using XML and XSL template transformation.

Things are stuck just because the generated .xls file doesn't contain the data from XSL template.

I think there is some problem in copying the template data into excelsheet. Please look at the code

```
   <?php
      include 'sendit.php';

      $outputDocument = 'report.xlsx';//$_REQUEST['output'];


      //Declare variables for file names.
      if (!isset($outputDocument)){
        $outputDocument = "report.xlsx";    
      }else {
        $outputDocument = 'report.xlsx';
      }
      $uniqueId = $_REQUEST['id'];

      $xmlfile = "employee.xml";
      $xsltFile = "SortName.xslt";
      $sourceTemplate = "SOW.xlsx";

      //Load the xml data and xslt and perform the transformation.
      $xmlDocument = new DOMDocument();
      $xmlDocument->load($xmlfile);

      $xsltDocument = new DOMDocument();
      $xsltDocument->load($xsltFile);

      $xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
      $xsltProcessor->importStylesheet($xsltDocument);

      //After the transformation, $newContentNew contains 
      //the XML data in the Open XML Wordprocessing format.
      $newContent =  $xsltProcessor->transformToXML($xmlDocument);

     //Copy the template document to the output file.
     if (copy($sourceTemplate, $outputDocument)) {

      //Open XML files are packaged following the Open Packaging 
      //Conventions and can be treated as zip files when 
      //accessing their content.
      $zipArchive = new ZipArchive();
      $zipArchive->open($outputDocument);

       //Replace the content with the new content created above.

       $zipArchive->addFromString("excel/document.xml", $newContent);
       $zipArchive->close();

       echo "Success! Download word document " . "<a href='http://localhost/demo/admin/exportDoc/export.xlsx'>HERE </a>";

       SendEmail();

        } else {
        echo "error";
        }

       ?>
```

here's the XML for this :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="SortNames.xsl"?>
             <dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
               <Employees>
                 <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
                 <LastName>Davolio</LastName>
                 <FirstName>Nancy</FirstName>
                 <Title>Sales Representative</Title>
                 <TitleOfCourtesy>Ms.</TitleOfCourtesy>
              </Employees>
             </dataroot>
```

Here is the XSLT file :-

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


          <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

         <!-- Output as an HTML file. -->
         <xsl:output method="html"/>
         <xsl:template match="/">
          <!-- Create a table with headings, then search for
               children of the Employees element. Once processing
                is completed, sort the table by the LastName field.
            -->
         <TABLE>
           <TR>
             <TH>Name</TH>
             <TH>Address</TH>
             <TH>Home Phone</TH>
           </TR>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="dataroot/Employees">
             <xsl:sort select="LastName" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
         </TABLE>
        </xsl:template>

          <!-- Process and output the child elements of
               the Employees element.
            -->
         <xsl:template match="dataroot/Employees">
            <TR>
               <TD>
                 <xsl:value-of select="FirstName" />
                  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                 <xsl:value-of select="LastName" />
                </TD>
                <TD>
                   <xsl:value-of select="Address" />
                   <br/>
                   <xsl:value-of select="City" />
                   <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Region"/>
                     <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                     <xsl:value-of select="PostalCode"/>
                </TD>
                <TD>
                      <xsl:value-of select="HomePhone" />

                        <!-- Test whether the phone number
                               has an extension. If not, skip the
                               template instruction.
                          -->
                      <xsl:if test="string-length(Extension)>0">
                       <xsl:text> Ext </xsl:text>
                       <xsl:value-of select="Extension" />
                      </xsl:if>
                  </TD>
               </TR>
              </xsl:template>
              </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Where is your XSL? Can you update your question with that? There might be an issue in there.

Comment: @MatthewGreen : Hii I am very new to these XSL templates. I have added the XSLT code here. Please see if it helps.

Comment: Your XSLT looks to transform fine except that your XML is missing a lot of the fields that you use in your XSLT. However, is there a reason you are outputting an HTML table? If you are trying to put the data in Excel I would think you would output a text delimited file instead.